Isometries and Isomorphisms on Hilbert spaces
I'm using Conways Functional Analysis book right now and I'm a bit confused about isometries and isomorphisms. I read online that an isometry between Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$ is an isomorphism, but Conway gave an example of an isometry
$$S:\ell^2\mapsto\ell^2 \ \ \text{by} \ \ S(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots)=(0,\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\dots)$$
which is clearly not an isomorphism, so there must be some subtlety that I'm missing, and I'm not sure what it is.

An isometry just preserves distances and an isometry which is also surjective is called an isomteric isomorphism.

An isometry only needs to satisfy $||S(x)||=||x||$ for all $x$. It is clearly injective, but not necessarily surjective.
